# Domain Controller Forgetting/Disregarding User is administrator

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I am part of the administrator group on our domain but I have issues upgrading/installing software on my own account. I either have to get another administrator account to login and do it or shift + right-click -> run as other user and use their account.

What I have tried:

1. Re-add to administrators group
2. Drop computer off domain -> Change computer name -> Re-add to domain (make a new record in DC)

I know a solution would to be make a new account but I can't because I have other machines I log into that I would like to keep consistent.

`whoami /all` returns:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be suspicious that a [Restricted Groups](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279301) Policy might be modifying the membership of your local Administrators group. Your disjoining / rejoining the domain and having this work as-expected for a short period supports that hypothesis.

I'd run a `net localgroup administrators` followed by a `whoami /all` from an elevated command prompt and compare the groups you're a member of to the groups that are granted local Administrators rights.

Edit:

Per that output you are a member of the local Administrators group. What isn't working right for you?

Comment: Why the negative vote..? net localgroup administrators returns that I am an administrator. whoami /all returns http://i.imgur.com/1TYvObl.png

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote you. I'll edit your question and add this image, though.

Comment: I dont have administrative rights to install programs/update.

Comment: What kind of error messages are you receiving, specifically, when you try to perform what specific tasks? You definitely have Administrator rights per that `whoami` output.

Comment: some programs tell me i need to redo the install as an administrator, other just silently look like theyre updating but then close, and never update. but once I run the program as a different admin user it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your domain administrators group is in the **local** computer administrators group ?

Comment: Under the builtin > administrators I am in there. Builtin groups cannot be added to other groups.